# HttpClient migration 3.x to 4.x

Tags: java, apache, post, entity, httpclient

I try to migrate my HttpClient library by Apache from 3.1 to 4.1.2.
I'm looking for the equivalent of this in 4.1.2:

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);        
method.addParameter("login", login);   
method.addParameter("password", password);
```

I try this, but the server doesn't recognize the request :

```
HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);   
MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
multipartEntity.addPart("login", new StringBody(login));
multipartEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody(password));
method.setEntity(multipartEntity);
```

any ideas ?

Comment: `any ideas?` I would use Wireshark to figure out what request actually is sent to the server.

Comment: Probably there is, but I don't know ;-) Wireshark would be only a click a way on my machine.

Comment: If you want logging, check out http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the parameters instead of creating a multipart request?

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("login", login);   
params.setParameter("password", password);

HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
method.setParams(params);
```